# replace local path in string to just display filename

Tags: vb.net

I am using a `file dialog` in *vb.net*, so when i choose a file it puts the local path into a `textbox`

How can i create a `string` that removes the path just leaving the filename in the variable?

Note: the local path may be different each time, i tried using a replace to replace the local path but if its different it doesnt work

i want to be able to put the file name that is selected in my code here:

```
Dim PDFFileName as String
PDFFileName = ..??
```

Comment: `System.IO.Path` has a number of functions to parse or combine file names

Comment: There is a property called **SafeFileName** that is exactly what you want (at least in openfiledialog objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`System.IO.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx), there are several useful methods like `GetFileNameWithoutExtension`:

```
Dim PDFFileName_WithExt = Path.GetFileName(fullPath)
Dim PDFFileName_NoExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullPath)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Plutonix already sayed use System.IO.Path.GetFileName(...)

Make 2 dims , SourceFolder and FileName.

The SourceFolder wil be the full path and the FileName  will just be the fileName.
Now you can use them according to your needs.

```
Dim SourceFolder As String = "D:\nog branden\Arian\Arian 5 meses video\M4H07839.MP4"
Dim FileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(SourceFolder)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    MsgBox(FileName)

End Sub
```